# Error in getting max value among all keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Using PySpark I want to get the max value among all keys of a pair RDD. The base RDD's data is like: `Social_Context.take(10):`

```python
[(1008044337136001024, 0.9343283582089552),
 (1008044334510428160, 3.103463393248575),
 (1008044334413852677, 0.7622047244094489),
 (1008044333260509185, 0.493006993006993),
 (1008044331641593856, 1.6094069529652353),
 (1008044329062092801, 0.481981981981982),
 (1008044326675460096, 1.3606889564336373),
 (1008044325710782469, 0.7228464419475655),
 (1008044323370295296, 0.46547314578005117),
 (1008044320757354497, 353.8944618599791)]
```

The key type is `int` and the value type is `float`. Trying to get the max value among all keys I did:

```python
Social_Context_MAX = Social_Context.map(lambda x : x[1]).max()
print(Social_Context_MAX)
```

But I got the error:

> `TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

I also tried to using Spark DataFrames.

```python
Social_Context_MAX = Social_Context.toDF(["id", "value"])
print(Social_Context_MAX.agg({"value": "max"}).collect()[0][0])
```

But again I got the error:

> ```python
> raise TypeError("Unexpected obj type: %s" % type(obj))
> TypeError: Unexpected obj type: <type 'float'>
> ```

**َUpdate**: I read the basic data from the JSON file into dataframe and after that, I convert it into RDD. Here is codes in more details:

```python
raw_data = spark.read.json("../input/Spark_tweets.json")
selected_data = raw_data.select("full_text", "id", "retweet_count", "user", "created_at", "entities")\
    .withColumn('verified', udf(getVerified)(raw_data.user))\
    .withColumn('followers_count', udf(getFollowerCount)(raw_data.user))\
    .withColumn('friends_count', udf(getFriendsCount)(raw_data.user))\
    .withColumn("hashtags", udf(getHashtags)(raw_data.entities))\
    .drop('user')\
    .drop('entities')
Social_Context = selected_data.rdd.map(lambda row : getSocialContext(row))
Social_Context_MAX = Social_Context.map(lambda x : x[1])
print Social_Context_MAX.max(key = lambda x : x[0])

def getSocialContext(row):
    A = int(row[2])
    B = int(row[5])
    C = float(row[6])

    if C == 0:
        return Default_Social_Context

    if (A > 0):
        res = (row[1], B * A / C)
        return res
    else:
        res = (row[1], B / C)
        return res
```

It works well except when I try to get the max of `Social_Context`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error based on the data you have provided (both solutions work for me). There is probably a bad record in your `rdd`.

Comment: You can try `rdd.filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (tuple, list))).map(lambda x: x[1]).max()`

Comment: @pault I test that but the same error. I will add the whole code maybe it helps.

Comment: The error message `TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` implies that somewhere it is attempting to use square brackets (`__getitem__`) on a `float`. Remember that spark is lazy, so it won't execute code until a transformation happens. Though you may think the error is happening in the call to `map`, it can be somewhere else- for example inside of your `getSocialContext` function or in one of the `udf`s you didn't include in the post.

Comment: What's `Default_Social_Context`? It better be a `tuple`.

Comment: @pault It's solved! I should return `(row[1], Default_Social_Context)` not just `Default_Social_Context`. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pault said, The error message `TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` implies that somewhere it is attempting to use square brackets `(__getitem__)` on a float. Remember that spark is lazy, so it won't execute code until a transformation happens. Though you may think the error is happening in the call to map, it can be somewhere else- for example inside of your `getSocialContext` function. The error was inside the `getSocialContext` function. The  line `return Default_Social_Context` should change to  `return (row[1], Default_Social_Context)`

Comment: There's no need to post this as an answer. The issue was a simple coding bug- you should just delete the question.